# Curve-fitting with 4 variables.

Tags: regression, data-analysis

I need to come up with a curve fit $f(w,x,y,z)$ based on 400 tabulated values as shown below. I was thinking of using the functional form

$$
f(w,x,y,z) = \sum_{i=0}^{i=2}\sum_{j=0}^{i=2}\sum_{k=0}^{i=2}\sum_{l=0}^{i=2}a_{ijkl}w^ix^jy^kz^l
$$

and determining the 81 values of $a_{ijkl}$ from least squares minimisation.

Can anybody volunteer a better suggestion? Are there any pre-processing tricks that I could exploit? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Try using fixed effects for $z$, since it oscillates in a predictable way. Or just start by plotting the f values for each w, x, y and z alone and seeing if there is a linear pattern or not.

Comment: There are patterns, but sadly not linear.